# Custom spaces with external monitor

Tags: spaces, display

I have a MacBook Pro plus an external 24" monitor. I'm also using 4 virtual spaces. With the external monitor they double, so I have 8 virtual spaces.

What I'd like to achieve now, and I don't know if it's possible at all, is to have 5 virtual spaces. 4 on my MacBook and only 1 for my external monitor. The reason for that is, that I have different applications (IDE, Terminal, chat, etc.) on my MacBook spread over the spaces, but on my external monitor I'd like to have always my web browser (the exact same window) showing, regardless on which virtual space I am on my MacBook.

Anyone an idea if that is possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in Spaces Preferences you can set the browser application to appear on all spaces. that's how i have my Terminal set up, among a few others. unless you move more apps onto your secondary monitor, the browser window should constanly stay visible even when switching around Spaces.

Answer (score 4):

This is a third party, non-free app, but it helps keep your applications organized across monitors and within Spaces as well. http://most-advantageous.com/optimal-layout/ (I am not the developer, just a happy customer.)